Prevent DDL on Blue during Postgres AWS Blue/Green
As per the AWS Blue/Green Documentation, one has to prevent all DDL (even simple things link create table) while one is in a Blue/Green replication situation.
My DB is about 5TB and AWS says that lazy loading from S3 happens with about 1TB per hour, so I will be in the Blue/Green situation for at least 5 hours (we want to wait until all loading is done before switching).
We have quite a few users that work on the DB daily, also creating tables (backup tables when modyfing things), dropping tables and so on.
How would you make sure that no one can destroy the Green environment by issuing DDL on Blue?

Take the log in priviledge away from all? That's a bit intrusive?
Is there a less strict way? Of just disallowing all DDL?
Maybe a better idea that I haven't had yet?


Just REVOKE the permissions to do any DDL

Thank you , @FrankHeikens, but from what I've read so far about postgres permissions there is no 'revoke all DDL' feature. At least to my knowledge. I see no way to prevent all DDL from all users in all schemas without also hampering their ability to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE at the same time.

Create one role that can do all the DDL (ddl_role), create one ROLE that can do all the CRUD (crud_role) and GRANT all your users permission for these two roles. You now only have to change the permissions for ddl_role to affect everyone who's granted these permissions
